# Loading a Xib with AutoLayout checked into view into my ViewController does not recognize touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I have an app with AutoLayout turned on at the storyboard level. I created a XIB and want to load that Xib's view into all of my VC's. I have everything setup in the XIB and everything works fine, *IF* I turn autolayout off on the XIB. If autolayout is turned on for the XIB then touch events are not recognized.

Is shutting autoLayout off just for the XIB going to cause any issues moving forward or is there a way to fix this autolay=ON not recognizing touch events?

Again the app works fine if autolayout=OFF (unchecked) on just the XIB.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong in setting up your constraints   (or in letting the system set them up for you). Ususally the cause of this problem is controls being outside the bounds of their superview. In viewDidAppear (not viewDidLoad), check the frame of the main view and see if it's correct.

Comment: It was that I hadn't set any constraints. I turned autolayout back on and setup constraints and it works.